# A tiny issue with exception handling interactment - not the correct output

Tags: java, exception

```
package test5555;
import java.util.InputMismatchException;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test5555 {

private static int[] randomInteger;

public static void main(String[] args) {

boolean validInput = false;
randomInteger = new int[100];
Random rand = new Random();
for (int i = 0; i < randomInteger.length; i++)
randomInteger[i] = rand.nextInt();
int indexPosition = 0;

Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); {
System.out.println("Please enter an integer for the array index position: ");

while(!validInput) 
{
try 
{

indexPosition = input.nextInt();
validInput = true;

System.out.println(randomInteger[indexPosition]);
} catch ( InputMismatchException | IndexOutOfBoundsException ex) {

System.out.print("Please enter a valid integer between 0 and 100 or type quit to exit: ");

String s = input.next();
if(s.equals("quit")){
System.exit(0);    
System.out.println(randomInteger[indexPosition]);
} 
}
}
}
}
}
```

- The code runs perfectly except for two minor hiccups that I cannot solve. When you run it you get `Please enter an integer for the array index position:`If you type a number above 100 or a string such as `bob` then you get `Please enter a valid integer between 0 and 100 or type quit to exit:`which is perfect. But if you type `quit` then you get `Please enter a valid integer between 0 and 100 or type quit to exit: BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 2 minutes 2 seconds)` so it quits it but it repeats the exception statement which I do not want.
- When you type a number above 100 and receive the `Please enter a valid integer between 0 and 100 or type quit to exit:` if you then type a correct integer the program will just turn off and it will say `BUILD SUCCESSFUL` instead of retrieving the number for you from the array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace your while loop code with below,

```
String s = null;
while(!validInput) 
{
try 
{
if(s != null){
    indexPosition = Integer.parseInt(s);
}
else{
indexPosition = input.nextInt();
}
System.out.println(randomInteger[indexPosition]);
validInput = true;
} catch ( InputMismatchException | NumberFormatException | IndexOutOfBoundsException ex ) {

System.out.println("Please enter a valid integer between 0 and 100 or type quit to exit: ");
input.nextLine();
s = input.next();
if(s.equals("quit")){
System.exit(0);
 } 
}
}
```

Please read this to get more idea on Scanner.
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html

In your case the problem is (As per doc)

> When a scanner throws an InputMismatchException, the scanner will not
>   pass the token that caused the exception, so that it may be retrieved
>   or skipped via some other method.

Answer (score 0):

- The behavior you describe in point 1 us not correct. If you type in a number and then quit it works "as expected"
- If you type in a string such as "bob" your nextInt() fails with an InputMissmatchException which means your "input.next()" call in the catch clause will read "bob" and see it's not equal to "quit" and just go back to the loop and block and wait for an "int".

  - In point 2. You type an int and you get an exception...but you've set  validInput to true already so you'll exit the loop. You need to set validInput after you print.

Answer (score 0):

If I got your question correctly, I would implement little differently. Please check if it fulfills your requirement.

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test5555 {

    private static int[] randomInteger;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        randomInteger = new int[100];
        Random rand = new Random();
        int indexPosition;

        for (int i = 0; i < randomInteger.length; i++) 
            randomInteger[i] = rand.nextInt();


        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter an integer for the array index position: ");

        while(true) {
            String strIndex = input.next();
            if(strIndex.equals("quit")) break;
            indexPosition = getIntVal(strIndex);

            if(indexPosition < 0 || indexPosition >= randomInteger.length) {
                System.out.print("Please enter a valid integer between 0 and " 
                            + randomInteger.length + " or type quit to exit: ");
                continue;
            }

            System.out.println(randomInteger[indexPosition]);
            break;
        }

        input.close();
    }

    protected static int getIntVal(String inputStr) {
        int result = -1;
        try {  
            result = Integer.parseInt(inputStr);
        } catch(NumberFormatException e) {}  
        return result;  
    }

}
```

Comment: thank you it works perfectly and does fulfill my requirement

Answer (score 0):

This part of your code is wrong

```
try 
{

indexPosition = input.nextInt();
validInput = true;

System.out.println(randomInteger[indexPosition]);
} catch ( InputMismatchException | IndexOutOfBoundsException ex) {
```

You are saying that your indexPosition is right before to check it, the line

```
validInput = true;
```

Should be later of check if the array have that position.

Right code:

```
...
indexPosition = input.nextInt();
System.out.println(randomInteger[indexPosition]); 
validInput = true;
....
```